# A very small microcontroller that can be programmed wirelessly

Tags: microcontroller, wireless

For fun, I'm building a microcontroller and a couple of sensors into a toy. The microcontroller must fit into a 2 cm wide cylinder. Also, removing it from the toy takes some time, so I'd like to be able to program it wirelessly. It doesn't matter how (IR, wifi, Bluetooth), as long as I don't have to remove it from the toy during testing.

I don't have much experience with these things, and so I don't know what to search for or if such a microcontroller even exists. What would you suggest?

Comment: What sort of micro is it - does it have external programme memory - does it have a bootload facility?

Comment: @Andyaka I haven't chosen a microcontroller yet, that's what I'm asking about. What's important is that I can program it without removing it from the toy.

Comment: Texas Instruments offers the [Chronos wireless programmable MSP430 platform](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/EZ430-Chronos?DCMP=Chronos&HQS=Other+OT+chronoswiki). Quote: "*The Wireless Update feature allows you to **change the firmware on the Chronos wirelessly**. There will be no need to open the enclosure to upgrade the program in use. Hardware debugging (setting breakpoints, single stepping, etc) is not possible over a BSL because physical access to the JTAG/Spy Bi-Wire is required for in-system programming.*" You could start with that kit (get the *black PCB* version), then switch.

Comment: Doesn't really get any easier than the TI Chronos, it has several sensors built in, and a built-in RF hub feature for integrating other sensors remotely.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh The TI Chronos looks useful! Do you know how large it is?

Comment: @Anna It fits inside a wristwatch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is going to be very difficult.

The typical way to do this is to have two MCU's.  One with a wireless connection that can program the other MCU's.  The programming MCU would require some firmware in it that can receive the wireless communications and twiddle the pins on the main MCU to program it.  You also have to power this circuit, which will put a burden on your toy's batteries.

This is a big project to make one MCU program the other, and the number of people who would benefit from this (a.k.a. pay money for it) is small.  That's why you don't see this in the market.  While cool, the market for it isn't large enough to justify the development costs.

If I were you, I would instead focus on a way to make the programming signals accessible without removing the PCB from the toy.  There are many ways to do this using fancy connectors or even just spring loaded "contacts" that touch metal bits on the toy.

Sometimes the straightforward approach is the best.  Skip the wireless.

Comment: I have the impression you dismiss a bootloader on the controller, why?

Comment: @jippie  I guess I shouldn't dismiss it outright, but it does depend on the MCU used, and lots of other factors.  If the OP wants to use something like an MSP430 that would only use Wireless for programming then wireless is probably more trouble than it's worth.  But if the MCU is an ARM, and would use wireless for other things then it might make sense to go the bootloader approach.

Comment: UART over IR or bluetooth?

Comment: One nice thing about bringing the pins out vs. a wireless bootloader is that you can do actual debugging with breakpoints and stuff rather than just programming the Flash.

Answer (score 0):

It's not going to be easy as Mr Kessner says but if you are going to try [here](http://www.ti.com/tool/flash-programmer) is a texas instruments device that probably will do what you want. The blurb says: -

The SmartRF Flash Programmer can be used to program the flash memory in Texas Instruments low-power RF system-on-chip devices and for upgrading the firmware and bootloader on the related evaluation boards and debugger (SmartRF Evaluation Boards, CC Debugger, etc.). SmartRF Flash Programmer **can also be used for programming the flash memory of MSP430 devices via the MSP-FET430UIF and the eZ430 dongle**.

The bit in bold implies that if you chose the MSP430 MCU you'll be able to programme it via rf. Good luck, not for the faint-hearted.

BTW I googled "msp430 rf bootloader" for the information.

Answer (score 0):

There's a new version of the arduino in development Called pinnochio.  It will support wireless programming,  and the mcu they use comes even in 9*9mm packages.

Comment: http://pinocc.io/ - It doesn't say anywhere that it is a version of the Arduino. Interesting product nevertheless.

Comment: In the page, they say "Arduino-compatible".

Comment: I'm sure Massimo Banzi would be quite upset if anything Arduino compatible claimed to be a ***version of the Arduino*** - In fact, he apparently threw quite a tantrum at [one KickStarter project](http://blog.arduino.cc/2012/11/26/kickstarter-trademarks-and-lies/) that made such a claim. Also, it appears that pinoccio changed their Arduino plans - the site does not claim to be related to the Arduino, except that one possibly outdated mention on the home page. I suspect they may have chosen to move away from such compatibility given Banzi's recent reactions to the use of the Arduino term!

Comment: As I understand, this is about trademarks,  not about using the arduino code

Answer (score 0):

Here's someone who created a circuit that programs an mcu via an opto-coupler.

https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=495706.0

Since an opto-coupler is just a led and a light sensor, if you use a clear plastic cylinder, you could put the sensor on the inside of the cylinder and the led on your external programmer , and make it work.

With some luck , it wouldn't be too hard.